# Update server dir after pushing to gitlab repo

Tags: php, git, bash, gitlab, githooks

We have the following setup - remote repository with gitlab gui.

Our webserver is located on another server and we have ssh access to it. We also have local copies of our dev site, our git setup right now just push to the repo in gitlab.

My goal is to automate the process and on every push to gitlab repo to update the server dir with latest changes.

I saw that for this purpose we should use webhooks or deploy keys. I want to avoid using cron job.

I created a bash script which performs git pull after certain php file is accessed.
However when I placed the url to this php file in webhook section in gitlab, nothing happened.

If I access the file manually by typing url in address bar it works ok.
When I try to test the hook I get 500 error and timeout.

Any recommendations how to improve this process or where Im going wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

The webhook does not just sends a get request to the provided URL, it also sends its data as JSON in raw data.

Can your script handle that?
Have a look at  [gitlab-webhook-push.php](https://gitlab.com/kpobococ/gitlab-webhook/blob/master/gitlab-webhook-push.php)

Answer (score 0):

The actual issue was that gitlab was not able to access our domain and was leading to timeouts, of course sys admins decided to restrict the access from external sources without notifying. Also it is good to mention that JSON raw data can be used for more complex solutions which is pretty nice.